# Website page not found and rendering issues

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have my site up and running but experiencing rendering issues in MS IE8 and IE9 but seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox.

There is also just one page in my site that keeps on returning a "Page Not Found" and unsure why as it's only the one page out of the rest that work.

The queries are:

1. Why does this link not work: http://solarinstallations.com.au/gallery-testimonials/ whereas other links found at main site do, i.e.: http://solarinstallations.com.au/
2. Any ideas as to why the rendering of my site is all over the place in both IE8 and IE9?

Comment: Does the /gallery/ page exist? If not that would be why you are getting a 404 page not found.  Can you be more specific about what rendering issues you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the rendering side of things, it turned out that I had invalid HTML and so ran the website through W3C Validator, where I corrected the issues and now all is fine.

With the "Page Not Found" issue, still wasn't sure what the reason was here so just deleted the page and re-created it. This solved this issue.